# McAfee VirusScan Enterprise is not retaining Access Protection Rules

Tags: anti-virus, mcafee

McAfee VirusScan is not retaining settings that are specified in the client for more than roughly five minutes, for example, I have enabled prevent mass mailing worm but after a short time has passed and the interface is reopened, the settings are unchecked. The client does obtain updates and configuration parameters from ePO, does that mean that setting specified in the clients will not remain permanent.

Is there a way to determine the policy setting via command line or some other means on the client to determine if ePO is pushing out a requirement not to retain settings?

[image: AV screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your client is managed by ePO and you want to change its policy, you need to break policy inheritance for that computer on the ePO server and define a new custom policy for it, also on the server. The default policy enforcement interval for ePO managed clients is 5 minutes, which would explain why your manually updated settings are being overwritten in 5 minute intervals.

Comment: Is there a setting in ePO that will allow a client to also specify custom settings, or I should said specify additional settings? Furthermore, is there a way that you can list everything that being applied to the client on the client-side, similarly to using _gpresult_ with AD clients?

Comment: @Astron You can see everything that is applying to the client by looking at what settings are checked. Its pretty transparent. Afaik, there is no way to let a client specify custom policies, they are enforced from the server. You will have to make a custom policy on the server for your machine. If a client could specify custom policies, it would open the door to malware changing whatever it wanted.